# Adding an identity column / primary key to an existing table in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

If you alter a SQL Azure table to add an identity column as primary key, does that create a new table and drop the original table?

I have a very large table and limited space. I am concerned that if I add the identity column (as PK) to this table, it will be be dropped and recreated, thus doubling the size of my database.

I have read that adding a column is just a metadata change but I am not sure about an identity and primary key column. I have read that reseeding an identity property will cause a table to be dropped and recreated but I am not sure that if adding an identity column performs the same operation as reseeding because it is adding a column.

Comment: Altering a table does not drop it no.

Comment: Hi @cjohns, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Larnu said, Altering a SQL Azure table to add an identity column as primary key won't create a new table and drop the original table.

You could test it with bellow sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(    C1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,    C2 nvarchar(50) not null
)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
VALUES ('a');

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
VALUES ('b');

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
VALUES ('c');

ALTER TABLE T1
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_identity PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (C1);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.T1;
```